# JQuery auto complete with asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a auto-complete function for a `TextBox` on a `.aspx` page. This is what I've tried :

```
<head runat="server">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript"src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   var availableTags = [
    "IT",
    "Marketing",
    "HR",
    "Accounting",
    "Management"

];
$( "#TextBox1" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
 });
</script>

</head>



<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="White"   ForeColor="Black" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I don't get any errors or anything but it the autocomplete doesn't show at all. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I did the same and it worked. However your form is not complete - as it stands it will not work because it's missing the form element which will throw an error. Please post a complete form. I suspect you have some id issues - could be the real id of the textbox differs from TextBox1 due to naming containers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include all the code to make it shorter - I do have a form element in the original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because on `asp.net`, your control will generate it's own `ID` when rendered as `HTML`, so your script of

```
$( "#TextBox1" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

wouln't find the `ID`, because it will usually rendered as

```
<input type="text" id="..._TextBox1"/>
```

so you could try to change the

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="White"   ForeColor="Black" ></asp:TextBox>
```

to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" BackColor="White"   ForeColor="Black" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

add the `ClientIDMode="Static"` so the ID will be rendered as it is